# Router with remote actors in akka.net

Tags: c#, akka.net

I'm trying to create sample router with two remote actors.
Here's my code

```
class Program
{

        public const string AkkaConfig = @"{
        akka {
            actor {
                provider = ""Akka.Remote.RemoteActorRefProvider, Akka.Remote""
                deployment {
                    /remoteecho1 {
                            remote = ""akka.tcp://Target@my1.lan:8090""
                    }
                    /remoteecho2 {
                            remote = ""akka.tcp://Target@my2.lan:8090""
                    }
            }
            remote{
                helios.tcp{
                    port = 0
                    hostname = localhost
                }
            }
        }
    }";

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        using (var system = ActorSystem.Create("Deployer", AkkaConfig))
        {
            var remoteEcho1 = system.ActorOf(Props.Create(() => new EchoActor()), "remoteecho1");
            var remoteEcho2 = system.ActorOf(Props.Create(() => new EchoActor()), "remoteecho2");

            var roundRobinGroup = new RoundRobinGroup(new[]
            {
                remoteEcho1,
                remoteEcho2
            });

            var coordinator = system.ActorOf(Props.Empty.WithRouter(roundRobinGroup),"coordinator");


            system.ActorOf(Props.Create(() => new HelloActor(coordinator)), "localactor");
            system.ActorSelection("/user/localactor").Tell(new SayHelloMessage());
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}

public class HelloActor:ReceiveActor
{
    private readonly IActorRef remoteActor;

    public HelloActor(IActorRef remoteActor)
    {
        this.remoteActor = remoteActor;
        Context.Watch(remoteActor);
        Receive<HelloMessage>(m =>
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Pingback from {1}: {0}", m.MessageText, Sender.Path);
        });

        Receive<SayHelloMessage>(m =>
        {
            var newMessage = new HelloMessage(Guid.NewGuid().ToString());
            remoteActor.Tell(newMessage);
        });
    }

    protected override void PreStart()
    {
        Context.System.Scheduler.ScheduleTellRepeatedlyCancelable(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1),
                TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1), Context.Self, new SayHelloMessage(), ActorRefs.NoSender);
    }
}

public class SayHelloMessage
{

}
```

The problem is that remoteActor.Tell(newMessage) in the code below doesn't send message to my actor

```
Receive<SayHelloMessage>(m =>
    {
        var newMessage = new HelloMessage(Guid.NewGuid().ToString());
        remoteActor.Tell(newMessage);
    });
```

When I pass remoteEcho actor to HelloActor constructor instead of router instance everything works fine. How to make that example work with Router?